# cannot convert byte to string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion, mailmerge

I am using `Syncfusion.DocIO` to perform mail merge but my document template is in SQL server DB I am accessing this document and then trying to apply merge but when I try to pass a parameter to `wordDocument` i get an error **cannot convert byte to string** although there is an overload method for the stream as well for `WordDocument`. How I can solve this issue and please help me with how I can perform mail merging using this code.
Thanks

```
  public ActionResult CreateDocument(GenerateTemp generateDoc)
        {
            var FileById = (from doc in db.Documents
                            where doc.D_Id.Equals(generateDoc.D_Id)
                            select new {doc.D_File}).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

            using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument(FileById.D_File))
            {
                string[] fieldNames = { "ContactName", "CompanyName", "Address", "City", "Country", "Phone" };
                string[] fieldValues = { "Nancy Davolio", "Syncfusion", "507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A", "Seattle, WA", "USA", "(206) 555-9857-x5467" };
                //Performs the mail merge
                document.MailMerge.Execute(fieldNames, fieldValues);
                //Saves the Word document to disk in DOCX format
                document.Save("Result.docx", FormatType.Docx, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response, HttpContentDisposition.Attachment);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Response can be *either* a page *or* a file, not both. Can you save to a MemoryStream and return the underlying byte array as ContentResult?

Answer (score 0):

From the given details, we suspect that you have tried to pass the byte or byte[] array as a parameter to WordDocument API instead of string. So, you have faced the compilation error (cannot convert byte to string) at your end. To achieve your end requirement, we suggest you have to convert the byte array into a stream and then pass the stream as a parameter to the WordDocument API. Please refer the below highlighted code example to achieve the same at your end and let us know if this helps you.

```
//Read all bytes from the file

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"../../Letter Formatting.docx");

//Converts the byte array into a stream

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

//Opens a template document from stream through constructor of WordDocument class

using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument(stream))

{

   string[] fieldNames = { "ContactName", "CompanyName", "Address", "City", "Country", "Phone" };

   string[] fieldValues = { "Nancy Davolio", "Syncfusion", "507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A", "Seattle, WA", "USA", "(206) 555-9857-x5467" };

   //Performs the mail merge

   document.MailMerge.Execute(fieldNames, fieldValues);

   //Saves the Word document to disk in DOCX format

   document.Save("Result.docx", FormatType.Docx, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response, HttpContentDisposition.Attachment);

}
```

If you think, we misunderstood any of your requirements, then kindly share us the following details of your end requirement, which will be helpful for us to provide exact solution.

1. Whether you have passed the byte or byte[] array as a parameter to a WordDocument.
2. Whether you have faced this error at compile time or run time.
   Based on the above details, we will analyze further and provide you the appropriate solution at the earliest.